# "object is not an instance of declaring class" at calling Method.invoke() with JoinPoint in @Before Spring AOP

Tags: java, reflection, aop, invoke

I want to call each getter of Argument object of each method of Controller of Spring framework through Spring AOP.
But when I call the getter, there is an exception which message is "object is not an instance of declaring class".

What am I wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

```java
@Before("execution(* *(..)) && within(@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller *)")
public void beforeController(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    MethodSignature methodSignature =  (MethodSignature)joinPoint.getSignature();
    StringBuffer methodFullName = new StringBuffer("");
    Class<?>[] parameters = methodSignature.getParameterTypes();
    for (Class<?> parameter : parameters) {
        methodFullName.append("\t" + parameter.getName() + "\n");
        Method[] methods = parameter.getDeclaredMethods();
        for (Method method : methods) {
            if (method.getName().startsWith("get")) {
                try {
                    Object object = method.invoke(parameter);
                    methodFullName.append("\t\t" + object.toString() + "\n");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(methodFullName.toString());
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be advised that in general it makes sense to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and not just a code snippet when asking a question. Otherwise you force others to create one in order to reproduce and understand your problem. In this case you don't even provide a full aspect, just a single advice. This is helpful, but a target class and maybe some Spring configuration would have been helpful too. You also do not explain what the purpose of your aspect is. So I had to figure out everything on my own. This was your free shot, please improve next time!

Comment: The first parameter to `Method.invoke()` is an instance of the class you got the `Method` from, not a parameter. If there are parameters they come after that. See the Javadoc. But you should throw it all away and have a look at `java.beans.Introspector`, or indeed `java.beans.Expression` and` java.beans.Statement`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your intention is to print all parameter types (class names) and for each parameter its properties via getter methods, assuming it is a Java Bean and has such getters. There are a few problems with your approach, though:

- Some classes have methods beginning with `get` which take parameters. You will get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments` when trying to call such methods, e.g. `public void java.lang.String.getBytes(int,int,byte[],int)`. Thus, you need to exclude such methods by filtering for those without parameters because property getters have no parameters.
- More subtly, you only want to filter for public methods because property getters are always public. There might be other, non-public `get*` methods which you ought to skip. Thus, you should call `getMethods()` instead of `getDeclaredMethods()` because the latter also gives you protected and private methods. Besides, you would get exceptions when trying to call non-public methods from other classes via reflection without making them accessible first via `method.setAccessible(true)`.
- Some methods matching these criteria might still not return anything you are interested in, such as

  - `public byte[] java.lang.String.getBytes()` for `String` objects and
  - `public final native java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()` for all object types because they inherit that method from their root super class `Object`.
- Some classes might not expose all their properties via getters because they are no Java Beans. But okay, let us assume this is not a problem.
- You could use a `StringBuilder` instead of a `StringBuffer` because with you local variable you do not need a thread-safe class.
- Why not add the method name or its full signature to your string buffer/builder? You named the variable `methodFullName`, after all, so why skip the method name?
- Last, but not least, there is a bug in your code which you might not have introduced in the first place if you had named your variables more clearly:

  - You declare `Class<?>[] parameters = methodSignature.getParameterTypes();` and then consequently use `for (Class<?> parameter : parameters)`.
  - You should have named them `parameterTypes` and then `parameterType`.
  - In that case you might have noticed that calling `method.invoke(parameter)` is actually `method.invoke(parameterType)`, which makes no sense because the first argument to `invoke` must be the actual object you want to invoke the method upon, not its *type*.
  - But it is easy to understand that this glitch went unnoticed because you might have thought that `parameter` is the actual parameter (a.k.a. method argument) you want to invoke the setter upon, which is is not. You are iterating over parameter types (classes).
  - The parameter objects themselves can be found via `joinPoint.getArgs()`. So you need the corresponding object from that `Object[]` with the exact same index as the current object from `methodSignature.getParameterTypes()` you are dealing with.
  - This is what causes your `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class`.

I am not sure why you want to use such a contrived approach for logging extensive details about your method calls. According to your pointcut you want to do that for all your controllers, i.e. you will use it often. It is kind of slow because it uses reflection, so it is up to you to decide if it is worth doing it in the first place. But assuming you answer that with yes, you could fix your code as follows.

Please note that I use a pure Jave + AspectJ example, not Spring AOP, which is why in my example you also see output for the `static main` method, which you would not in Spring AOP because there you can only intercept non-static methods which in AspectJ you need to exclude via `execution(!static * *(..))`, which I am not doing here so as not to change your original pointcut.

I am also adding additional log output (always beginning with "#") so you can see what is going on because you are not logging method names.

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class MyBaseBean {
  protected int id;

  public MyBaseBean(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Person extends MyBaseBean {
  private String name;
  private String address;
  private int zipCode;
  private String city;

  public Person(int id, String name, String address, int zipCode, String city) {
    super(id);
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.zipCode = zipCode;
    this.city = city;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public String getAddress() {
    return address;
  }

  public int getZipCode() {
    return zipCode;
  }

  public String getCity() {
    return city;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Person [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", address=" + address + ", zipCode=" + zipCode + ", city=" + city + "]";
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@Controller
public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Application().printPerson(new Person(11, "John Doe", "123 Main St", 12345, "Hometown"));
    new Application().doSomething("Hello world!", 3);
  }

  public void printPerson(Person person) {
    System.out.println(person);
  }

  public void doSomething(String message, int repetitions) {
    for (int i = 0; i < repetitions; i++)
      System.out.println(message);
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.MethodSignature;

@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
  @Before("execution(* *(..)) && within(@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller *)")
  public void beforeController(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    System.out.println("#" + joinPoint);
    Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
    MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
    StringBuilder methodFullName = new StringBuilder(methodSignature + "\n");
    Class<?>[] parameterTypes = methodSignature.getParameterTypes();
    int argsIndex = -1;
    for (Class<?> parameterType : parameterTypes) {
      argsIndex++;
      methodFullName.append("\t" + parameterType.getName() + "\n");
      System.out.println("  #" + parameterType);
      Method[] methods = parameterType.getMethods();
      for (Method method : methods) {
        String methodName = method.getName();
        if (methodName.startsWith("get") && !methodName.equals("getClass") && method.getParameterCount() == 0) {
          System.out.println("    #" + method);
          try {
            Object object = method.invoke(args[argsIndex]);
            methodFullName.append("\t\t" + object.toString() + "\n");
          } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      }
    }
    System.out.println(methodFullName.toString());
  }
}
```

As you can see, I am filtering out `getClass` and also `get*` methods with parameters, but in the following log you will see that `String.getBytes()` is still being called and its result (a byte array's `toString` representation) printed for `String` parameters. So this solution is not perfect and I don't like it anyway, I just wanted to answer your question.

A better alternative would be to make sure that your classes have meaningful `toString()` methods, then you could just print the arguments from `joinPoint.getArgs()` instead of calling getter methods on each of them.

```
#execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(String[]))
  #class [Ljava.lang.String;
void de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(String[])
    [Ljava.lang.String;

#execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.printPerson(Person))
  #class de.scrum_master.app.Person
    #public java.lang.String de.scrum_master.app.Person.getName()
    #public java.lang.String de.scrum_master.app.Person.getAddress()
    #public int de.scrum_master.app.Person.getZipCode()
    #public java.lang.String de.scrum_master.app.Person.getCity()
    #public int de.scrum_master.app.MyBaseBean.getId()
void de.scrum_master.app.Application.printPerson(Person)
    de.scrum_master.app.Person
        John Doe
        123 Main St
        12345
        Hometown
        11

Person [id=11, name=John Doe, address=123 Main St, zipCode=12345, city=Hometown]
#execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomething(String, int))
  #class java.lang.String
    #public byte[] java.lang.String.getBytes()
  #int
void de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomething(String, int)
    java.lang.String
        [B@78c03f1f
    int

Hello world!
Hello world!
Hello world!
```

---

**Update:** If you prefer a more readable solution involving Java streams with filters, you can also do it like that (additional debug statements removed):

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.MethodSignature;

@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
  @Before("execution(* *(..)) && within(@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller *)")
  public void beforeController(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
    MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
    Class<?>[] parameterTypes = methodSignature.getParameterTypes();
    StringBuilder logMessage = new StringBuilder(methodSignature + "\n");
    int argsIndex = 0;

    for (Class<?> parameterType : parameterTypes) {
      Object parameter = args[argsIndex++];
      logMessage.append("\t" + parameterType.getName() + "\n");
      Stream.of(parameterType.getMethods())
        .filter(method -> method.getParameterCount() == 0)
        .filter(method -> method.getName().startsWith("get"))
        .filter(method -> !method.getName().equals("getClass"))
        .forEach(method -> logMessage.append("\t\t" + invokeMethod(method, parameter) + "\n"));
    }

    System.out.println(logMessage.toString());
  }

  private Object invokeMethod(Method method, Object targetObject) {
    try {
      return method.invoke(targetObject);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return "<ERROR>";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The `Method.invoke()` call will still fail for the same reason.

Comment: No, it won't. If you run my code you will see that it runs successfully as also indicated by my console log.

Comment: @kriegaex Thanks for your detail answer.
I solved this issue. 
I need to use Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs(); instead of Class<?>[] parameters = methodSignature.getParameterTypes();

Comment: This is exactly what I have written in my answer!!! I described it in writing and it is contained in my sample code. So I solved this issue for you (along with all the other smaller issues), you didn't.

Comment: Please be so fair as to upvote and accept my answer.